# Printing both stanza and line numbers in the critical apparatus of a poem (reledmac)

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac

I am working on the critical edition of an poem written in "ottava rima" (each stanza has 8 lines), and I am using the package **reledmac**. I need both the stanza number and the line number to be printed in the apparatus below the text, next to the lemma. E.g. the word *hello* in line 7 of stanza 15 should be printed in the apparatus as:

**15**.7 hello] etc.

I have managed to print the line number, but I could not find a way to have the stanza number also appear. I am conscious of the banality of my question, but: does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it is a bit difficult without an example to test it, yet the manual suggests the command `\Xstanza[<s>]` (chapter 7.4.9, "printing stanza number") for that purpose.